# how to run apktool from webcode (php)

Tags: php, apk

Essentially when a user uploads a .apk file I need to decode it and extract some information from the AndroidManifest.xml file inside the apk.
When I run this command from command line `apktool decode BluetoothChat.apk` everything is fine.
The output:

```
I: Baksmaling...
I: Loading resource table...
I: Loaded.
I: Loading resource table from file: /home/tashax/apktool/framework/1.apk
I: Loaded.
I: Decoding file-resources...
I: Decoding values*/* XMLs...
I: Done.
I: Copying assets and libs...
```

However, if I try to execute it from the webcode using php `exec()` function, I get an error. It fails on `I: Loading resource table from file: /home/tashax/apktool/framework/1.apk`, I'm thinking it cannot find the  framework/1.apk file . This seems to be the setup issue, had anyone done something similar or knows what I'm missing?
Here's are the errors from apktool when ran from web:

```
I: Baksmaling... 
I: Loading resource table... 
I: Loaded. 
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=versionCode, value=0x00000001 
W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=versionName, value=0x0000000d 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at   java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157) 
at brut.androlib.res.util.ExtMXSerializer.writeAttributeValue(ExtMXSerializer.java:38) 
at org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer.attribute(MXSerializer.java:673) 
at   org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.XmlSerializerDelegate.attribute(XmlSerializerDelegate.java:106) 
at org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.writeStartTag(StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.java:267) 
at org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.event(StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.java:211) 
at brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder.decode(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:46) 
at  brut.androlib.res.decoder.ResStreamDecoderContainer.decode(ResStreamDecoderContainer.java:34) 
at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ResFileDecoder.decode(ResFileDecoder.java:100) 
at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.decode(AndrolibResources.java:114) 
at brut.androlib.Androlib.decodeResourcesFull(Androlib.java:93) 
at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:98) 
at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:128) 
at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:65)
```

Thanks!

Comment: i guess some environment variable setting is missing for this from Web

Comment: I am still not able to find a solution for this..

Comment: ended up using [AXMLPrinter2.jar](https://code.google.com/p/android4me/downloads/detail?name=AXMLPrinter2.jar&can=2&q=) to read the AndroidManifest.xml file or you could aapt dump badging command. apktool requires you to run it as regular user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the root cause.

Please notice this line of output (run from command line):
I: Loading resource table from file: /home/tashax/apktool/framework/1.apk

When apktool is run in PHP, the current user does not have home directory, then apktool would not be able to create ~/apktool/framework/1.apk successfully.

Check the options of apktool. There is an option to change framework files directory:
       --frame-path 
            Use the specified directory for framework files

So, change the command line and add this option:
apktool decode --frame-path /tmp BluetoothChat.apk

It works now.

Comment: I figured it had to do with webuser not having home directory but concluded that there is no way around it. Amazing that you figured it out. Even though I ended up using a different tool to get the job done, this will be super helpful for next time, thanks for sharing!

Comment: By default, apktool does not have a --frame-path option in b[uild] mode. If you want to use apktool to rebuild an APK in PHP, please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=427. connor.tumbleson provided a perfect fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error

`W: Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=android, name=versionName, value=0x0000000d`

Means that the resource couldn't be found. The framework(s) you installed are either not from that ROM / Phone (Where-ever that APK originated from), or Apktool is out of date.

Apktool v1.5.0 has support up to Android 4.1.x, while Android 4.2 is not yet supported.

Comment: Well, I got same problem. apktool cannot work from PHP, but the exactly same line of code to execute apktool, CAN run under terminal.